# How to get the ip address without ifconfig or ip command in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, command-line, server

Today I got a new Ubuntu server. I tried to get its IP address with the `ifconfig` or `ip` commands.

But I got a `command not found` error. I searched the errors on Google, and it looks like I need to install package to run these commands.

But I don't have `sudo` access.  Is there any other way to get the IP address without these commands?

Comment: You can try some of the solutions in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/365225/70524. Is `networkctl` available? Try `networkctl status`

Comment: All supported releases of Ubuntu include the `ip` command, so it's confusing which "*new Ubuntu server*" you got. Can you shed some light on that?

Answer (score 3):

If you're lucky (and hostnames are set up properly), `hostname -i` will provide the local IP address. If not, or if you have multiple IP addresses, it will probably return the localhost address `127.0.0.1`. The command `hostname -I` will report all machine-local IP (v4 and v6) addresses.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Python. It is installed by default on most distributions.  It is very easy to use.

```
$python
>>> import netifaces as ni
>>> ni.interfaces()
['lo', 'eth0','eth1','eth2']
>>> ni.ifaddresses('eth0')
{17: [{'addr': '02:93:07:be:da:d9', 'broadcast': 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'}], 2: [{'addr': '10.0.0.76', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'broadcast': '10.0.0.255'}], 10: [{'addr': 'fe80::93:7ff:febe:dad9%eth0', 'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::'}]}
```

In the above example, there are four interfaces lo, eth0, eth1, eth2. The ip address for eth0 is 10.0.0.76.

A Linux server can have more than one network interface. You can check out my post on my website [here](https://www.howtouselinux.com/post/check-ip-address-in-linux) to get more info about this.

This Python script displays the mac address, ip address, netmask for each network interface.

Here's another way to get the IP address without using a python package:

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct

def get_ip_address(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
        s.fileno(),
        0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR
        struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
    )[20:24])

get_ip_address('eth0')  # '192.168.0.110'
```

You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196932/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-from-a-nic-network-interface-controller-in-python) to get more about how to use Python to get ip address.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply a *user* on an Ubuntu server, and the administrator has disabled your access to certain tools, it may be difficult to determine *which* tools you have available.  The `ip` command is typically available to end-users, but perhaps there's a path issue (unlikely):

```
/usr/bin/ip addr show
# or
/bin/ip addr show
# or (could be restricted)
/sbin/ip addr show
```

Alternatively, you can try using `curl` to access an external service that will detect your public IP.  There are quite a few out there - I just went with the first search result I found:

```
curl ifconfig.me/all
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution based on @howtouselinux's answer that you can directly copy and paste.

```
python3 <<HEREDOC
import netifaces as ni
import pprint
interfaces = ni.interfaces()
print("\n", "Interfaces:", interfaces)
for iface in interfaces:
    ifconfig = ni.ifaddresses(iface)
    pprint.pprint(ifconfig)
HEREDOC
```

Output

```
Interfaces: ['lo', 'enp0s1']
{2: [{'addr': '127.0.0.1', 'netmask': '255.0.0.0', 'peer': '127.0.0.1'}],
 10: [{'addr': '::1',
       'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff/128'}],
 17: [{'addr': '00:00:00:00:00:00', 'peer': '00:00:00:00:00:00'}]}
{2: [{'addr': '192.168.1.215',
      'broadcast': '192.168.1.255',
      'netmask': '255.255.255.0'}],
 10: [{'addr': 'fe80::b:d8ff:fe61:58a%enp0s1',
       'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::/64'}],
 17: [{'addr': '02:0b:d8:65:0b:8a', 'broadcast': 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'}]}
```